# network: secure traffic between servers

Tags: networking, security

I am trying to secure communication between serverA to serverB on port 2020

For this purpose I have separate network interface which I want to use and set up secure communication using SSL.

Please note there is nothing in between. I mean nothing I could have access to like proxy, network load balancer or anything of this kind.

Is that possible ? Could you please drive me to the right reading ?

please advise

Comment: Can you clarify "When I say nothing I mean nothing I could use to make it happen like proxy, network load balancer or anything of this kind"? It's hard to follow.

Comment: I have no access to any network devices as explained.

Comment: What is the type of link used between A and B ?

Comment: just tcp/ip protocol, both of the servers are in the Internet.

Comment: What sort of communication are you doing? Are you writing your own software to communicate between the two? Is it web traffic? It's very hard to suggest how to secure the communication without this information.

Comment: no, I am not writing any software and it's not a web traffic specifically. I'd like to reuse something that must already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing client-server application that uses server port 2020, you can use [SSH tunneling](http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html) to encrypt it.

The client is whichever computer initiates the connection, e.g. your "serverA" might act as the client.

Comment: I would like to use SSL specifically. I am aware it can be done easily via ssh however, requirement is different.

Comment: @m1k3y02: See http://security.stackexchange.com/a/1600